# Elementor just keeps loading

Tags: wordpress, elementor

If I want to edit a page in wordpress with elementor, elementor just keeps loading and I can't edit anything.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

I have deactivated all plugins of wordpress but the try is not solved

Comment: There may be JS error in console. Please check it.

Comment: Hi, i saw no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be two reasons...

1. First might be the fact that elementor has an error with some plugin. The way to fix that would be to start trying different combinations with plugins.
2. Second thing you could do would be to edit your PHP Memory limit. For that you have two options - First is to edit the wp-config file and secont to increase the memory limit from cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor.

I will also add a link here, that could help you with additional info.
[Extra information](https://elementor.com/help/elementor-widget-panel-not-loading/)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. If I change the theme it works. That's weird isn't it?

Comment: Okay, what theme are you using? Do you have any other page builder apps installed? It's seems to have somekind of error with you current theme, although Elementor should be compatible with most of the themes out there.